# can not establish connection between serial and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arduino

I was trying to read data from serial and spring boot so that I can read data from my Arduino so I used this code

```
package com.example.databasedemo;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class SerialTest implements SerialPortEventListener {
    SerialPort serialPort;
    /** The port we're normally going to use. */
    private static final String PORT_NAMES[] = {                  "/dev/tty.usbserial-A9007UX1", // Mac OS X
            "/dev/ttyUSB0", // Linux
            "COM4", // Windows
    };
    private BufferedReader input;
    private OutputStream output;
    private static final int TIME_OUT = 2000;
    private static final int DATA_RATE = 9600;

    public void initialize() {
        CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
        Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        //First, Find an instance of serial port as set in PORT_NAMES.
        while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
            for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
                if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                    portId = currPortId;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (portId == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not find COM port.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                    TIME_OUT);
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            // open the streams
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
            output = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }


    public synchronized void close() {
        if (serialPort != null) {
            serialPort.removeEventListener();
            serialPort.close();
        }
    }
    public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=null;
                if (input.ready()) {
                    inputLine = input.readLine();
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerialTest main = new SerialTest();
        main.initialize();
        Thread t=new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                //the following line will keep this app alive for 1000    seconds,
                //waiting for events to occur and responding to them    (printing incoming messages to console).
                try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException    ie) {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Started");
    }
}
```

but when i run the app if the arduino is running the string boot give me this error :

```
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\IdeaProjects\databasedemo\hs_err_pid12940.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and when the spring boot is running the Arduino
 gives me this error

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM4": Access is denied.
```

i did not found a way to fix it it look like when the first is reading the other is bloked and when the other is sending the other is bloked how can i fix it

this is the  file i couldn't post all of it is too big

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180003990, pid=23176, tid=6896
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0+28) (build 11+28)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11+28, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x3990]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\Desktop -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=55606:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.example.databasedemo.SerialTest

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 4 cores, 7G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 17763 (10.0.17763.475)
Time: Sun Jun 23 22:18:34 2019 W. Central Africa Standard Time elapsed time: 1 seconds (0d 0h 0m 1s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001599e5af000):  JavaThread "Thread-0" [_thread_in_native, id=6896, stack(0x00000053b3500000,0x00000053b3600000)]

Stack: [0x00000053b3500000,0x00000053b3600000],  sp=0x00000053b35fe320,  free space=1016k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native 

code)
    C  [rxtxSerial.dll+0x3990]
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort.readArray([BII)I+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialInputStream.read([BII)I+212
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes()I+135 java.base@11
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead([CII)I+112 java.base@11
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read([CII)I+180 java.base@11
j  java.io.InputStreamReader.read([CII)I+7 java.base@11
j  java.io.BufferedReader.fill()V+145 java.base@11
j  java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Z)Ljava/lang/String;+44 java.base@11
j  java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()Ljava/lang/String;+2 java.base@11
j  com.example.databasedemo.SerialTest.serialEvent(Lgnu/io/SerialPortEvent;)V+24
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort.sendEvent(IZ)Z+382
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort.eventLoop()V+0
j  gnu.io.RXTXPort$MonitorThread.run()V+12
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0xffffffffb35ff158


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x0000000180003990 rxtxSerial.dll
RAX=
[error occurred during error reporting (printing register info), id 0xc0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffbb1654d76]
```

Comment: Can you please post contents of the file C:\Users\ELA_HIDRI\IdeaProjects\databasedemo\hs_err_pid12940.log here @ElaHidri so we can take a look at the exact error you are getting if the arduino is running. Thank you. As for the second error, looks like your windows machine is not allowing access to the arduino to COM4 port.

Comment: yes it looks like that  you can find the contents of the file  added